# What happens to existing face tags in Photos once iOS 10 and macOS Sierra drop?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, macos

I spent a lot of time organising Faces in Photos.app. I use the iCloud Photo Library, so the library in OSX and iOS was one and the same, and you could even search for people's names from the iOS Photos app, even though there was no Faces album.

Today I've installed iOS 10 and I see it has started scanning the entire library for faces, apparently oblivious of already existing tags.

Does anyone know if the face tags from OSX El Capitan will be preserved at all?

Comment: did you ever upgrade? What happened?